# Negative Cronbach's alpha – recode data, or use another method?

Tags: r, reliability, cronbachs-alpha, item-analysis

Below is a made up scenario to exemplify my issue.

I have two questionnaires asking individuals how much headache they have compared with 7 days ago. The scale is from much less through little less, same, little more to much more, coded as -2, -1, 0, +1, and +2, respectively. This was asked in two different ways: how much headache they have today vs 7 days ago, and how much headache they have today vs 1 week ago. We want to see how these are correlated.

Example code:

```
data <- data.frame(c(NA, NA, 0, 1, 0, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, -1, 0, 0, 1, 0),
                   c(NA, -2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0))
```

The first column is the 7-day question and the second column is the 1-week question. Now, if I use the `ltm` package here with the following code:

```
cronbach.alpha(data, standardized = F, CI = T, na.rm = T)
```

I get alpha = $-0.115$ ($95$% CI $-1.365$ to $0.522$)

How come I get the negative score, and what can I do to correct this? Or, would you recommend a different test altogether, for this data set? I've read other similar questions but without really understanding how I can change my analysis to correct this.

Answer (score 4):

A negative Cronbach's alpha can occur when some of the components (items) are negatively correlated (see also my Youtube video on negative Cronbach's alpha: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jyKAFoLcwGw). Have you checked the inter-item correlation? Obviously, your two items ask about the exact same thing, so they should not be negatively correlated. Could there be an error in your data?

Comment: Hi Christian. I'm grateful that you reply, as I in fact just watched your video before posting this question. ;-) I should add that my example of questions is a made-up scenario to avoid posting study results here. But in essence we've asked about the same thing in two different ways in the two questionnaires. 

I've not checked the inter-item correlation. Would you use performance package and item_intercor() for that?

Comment: If I use item_intercor() for the above data, I get 0.14, which I understand is a bit low (it should be between 0.2 and 0.4)?

Comment: It is surprising that two questions that ask about the exact same thing would only show a (very small!) correlation of .14. I would expect a much larger correlation. Could there be some other problem with the data? Was the sample size small?

Comment: Yes, the sample size was 50 as in this example, so perhaps this is the issue, and thus not possible to correct for?

Comment: Have you looked at a scatterplot? Could there be any outliers or extreme values that distort the relationship? Once again, the correlation seems unusually small.

Answer (score 1):

##### Limited Information

Setting aside my grief about Cronbach's alpha for a second (see Flora, 2020 for a full accounting), I would generally advise against ever having just two questions for measuring a latent construct. While it is certainly possible to achieve, there are a number of issues that can arise such as yours with such limited information:

- With just two items, your variance between items is very limited and thus provides less information/precision about your construct (Eisinga et al., 2013). This becomes magnified when the number of responses is very limited (such as a binary response, see Simms et al., 2019). Coefficient alpha is prone to inflation simply by adding items (because of the formulation of alpha determines this), but that is another story.
- If you are fitting this to a latent variable modeling framework, this will result in under-identified models (see [here](https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/r/seminars/rcfa/)). Because I am more partial to McDonald's omega coefficient, this would be a problem for me if I wanted to get factor loadings to estimate the reliability.

> How come I get the negative score, and what can I do to correct this?
> Or, would you recommend a different test altogether, for this data
> set?

It doesn't sound like this was done based on previous research. See what others have done and what has worked first. I would then rerun a pilot using more items and items that in the research are more likely to approximate your latent construct (see Thabane et al., 2010 for a guide on pilot studies). Then based off the results you can tweak that to see what makes the most sense for capturing your latent variable. Then after you can run a full scale study with more participants and measure what this looks like.

##### Edit

Christian noted that my concerns about alpha items is not warranted. Remember that the formula for Cronbach's alpha is defined as:

$$
a = \frac{k}{k-1}(1-\frac{\sum_{k=1}^k {\sigma^2_{y}}_i}{\sigma_y})
$$

where $k$ is the number of items and $\sigma^2_y$ is the variance of the items. Notice that one increases the alpha *ipso facto* the inclusion of the $k$ parameter in this formula. To test this, we can run a simple simulation of weakly correlated variables ($r=.10$) and see how the number of items may increase the alpha coefficient. Running a simulation with a substantial number of items for this e.g. $k > 100$ or boots makes this simulation slow, so I just use $k <= 50$ for this simulation, which draws a sample of $n=500$ subjects (to stabilize estimation), and $B=100$ simulations (to include uncertainty).

The code:

```
#### Load Libraries ####
library(psych)
library(MASS)
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(123)

#### Sim Data and Coefficient ####
simulate_alpha <- function(num_items, correlation) {
  # Create a correlation matrix
  corr_matrix <- matrix(correlation, num_items, num_items)
  diag(corr_matrix) <- 1
  
  # Generate multivariate normal data
  data <- mvrnorm(n = 500, mu = rep(0, num_items), Sigma = corr_matrix)
  
  # Compute Cronbach's alpha
  alpha_res <- alpha(data)
  
  return(alpha_res$total$raw_alpha)
}

#### Define Items and Sims ####
num_items <- seq(5, 50, 1)
correlation <- 0.10
num_simulations <- 100

#### Run Sims ####
results <- expand.grid(num_items = num_items, simulation = 1:num_simulations)
results$alpha <- suppressMessages(
  with(results, mapply(simulate_alpha, num_items, correlation))
)

#### PLot Results ####
ggplot(results,
       aes(x = num_items, 
           y = alpha)) +
  geom_point(alpha=.4,
             position = "jitter") +
  geom_smooth(method = "gam",
              formula = y ~ s(x),
              color="darkred") +
  labs(x = "Number of Items", 
       y = "Cronbach's Alpha",
       title = "Simulation of Cronbach's Alpha")+
  theme_classic()+
  scale_x_continuous(n.breaks = 10)+
  scale_y_continuous(n.breaks = 10)
```

We can see that even with poor correlations for the items, our alpha coefficient almost necessarily increases until reaching an upper boundary near $a = .90$. This is despite the fact that the items are tau equivalent, as they should all be close to the same correlation. For a relevant paper which discusses this point, see Kopalle & Lehmann, 1997, which shows that alpha can mask uncorrelated items for this very reason. Notice also that alpha estimation is very unstable with even 5 items, whereas as items increase, the uncertainty in the estimate decreases and becomes more consistent:

[image]

Note that this simulation is very slow. This specific run took about 3 minutes. One can modify the parameters of this simulation from my script by changing the correlation or the items to see how this is affected over a range of values (strong correlations between items for example basically net very little increase in alpha, which makes sense). As to the commentary about under-identification, from the link I provided:

> Technically a three item CFA is the minimum number of items for a one
> factor CFA as this results in a saturated model where the number of
> free parameters equals to number of elements in the
> variance-covariance matrix (i.e., the degrees of freedom is zero).
> Suppose that one of the data collectors accidentally lost part of the
> survey and we are left with only Items 4 and 5 from the SAQ-8. When
> there are only two items, you have $2(3)/2 = 3$ elements in the variance covariance
> matrix. As you can see in the path diagram below, there are in fact
> five free parameters: two residual variances , two loadings and a
> factor variance. Even if we used the marker method, which the default,
> that leaves us with one less parameter, resulting in four free
> parameters when we only have three to work with.

##### References

- Eisinga, R., Grotenhuis, M. T., & Pelzer, B. (2013). The reliability of a two-item scale: Pearson, Cronbach, or Spearman-Brown? International Journal of Public Health, 58(4), 637–642. https://doi.org/10.1007/s00038-012-0416-3
- Flora, D. B. (2020). Your coefficient alpha is probably wrong, but which coefficient omega is right? A tutorial on using R to obtain better reliability estimates. Advances in Methods and Practices in Psychological Science, 3(4), 484–501. https://doi.org/10.1177/2515245920951747
- Kopalle, P. K., & Lehmann, D. R. (1997). Alpha inflation? The impact of eliminating scale items on Cronbach’s alpha. Organizational Behavior and Human Decision Processes, 70(3), 189–197. https://doi.org/10.1006/obhd.1997.2702
- Simms, L. J., Zelazny, K., Williams, T. F., & Bernstein, L. (2019). Does the number of response options matter? Psychometric perspectives using personality questionnaire data. Psychological Assessment, 31(4), 557–566. https://doi.org/10.1037/pas0000648
- Thabane, L., Ma, J., Chu, R., Cheng, J., Ismaila, A., Rios, L. P., Robson, R., Thabane, M., Giangregorio, L., & Goldsmith, C. H. (2010). A tutorial on pilot studies: The what, why and how. BMC Medical Research Methodology, 10(1), 1. https://doi.org/10.1186/1471-2288-10-1

Comment: Thank you Shawn for your interesting comments. Unfortunately, this is not my study design and I'm simply looking to make the best out of it. I don't have the choice to perfect the data collection, even if that is always tempting of course. So I just have to find the best way to analyze what I have at hand now.

Comment: I disagree with at least some of Shawn's comments here. Cronbach's alpha is not "inflated" when you add more (tau-equivalent) items to a unidimensional, tau-equivalent scale. This is one of the fundamental laws of measurement (test) theory: Longer scales (i.e., scales with a larger number of items) are more reliable, all other things being equal. Also, a single-factor, tau-equivalence CFA model with two items is not statistically underidentified. An essential tau-equivalence model is just identified with two items and a strict tau-equivalence model is even overidentfied with 1 df.

Comment: See my edit. I could be wrong about the under-identification issue (I defer to UCLA's wisdom on that) but the simulation I provide seems to indicate that $k$ items makes a difference.

Comment: Yes, adding items does increase alpha. But this is as it should be/a good thing. With more items, reliability increases because errors of measurement have more opportunity to average out. The term "inflation" seems to suggest that this is something bad. It is not. The problem is that the purpose of alpha is often misunderstood and that it is frequently misapplied (e.g., applied to multidimensional non-tau-equivalent scales) in which case it is trivially misleading. When you apply it properly (i.e., to tau-equivalent measures), there is no need to be concerned about "inflation."

Comment: Regarding identification: Cronbach's alpha implies (essential or strict) tau equivalence, that is, a single factor model with equal loadings and uncorrelated error variables. An essential tau equivalence model for two indicators has 5 parameters (one factor variance, two intercepts, two residual variances). A strict tau-equivalence model in addition has equal intercepts and therefore only 4 parameters. With two variables, you have 5 pieces of information (two means, two variances, one covariances) which is sufficient to estimate the parameters of the essential or strict tau-equivalence model.

Comment: Regarding identification II: See Steyer, R. (1989). Models of classical psychometric test theory as stochastic measurement models: Representation, uniqueness, meaningfulness, identifiability, and testability. Methodika, 3, 25–60.

Comment: Thanks I'll give that a look. I agree that alpha isn't *necessarily* a bad thing. The issue mainly is that there are plenty of things that get disguised by alpha which are never present unless you apply linear models to them (such as the factor analysis case). A very easy example is the presence of linear constants in items, which are completely ignored by alpha but cause `lavaan` to crap the bed.

Comment: By the way, McDonald's omega behaves in the same way (it increases as the number of tau-congeneric items increases). This is a general (and logical) property of any reliability coefficient. Same for the Spearman-Brown formula (composite reliability for tau-parallel measures).